# Check if a value matches another table within group in pandas or SQL

Tags: pandas, group-by, hive

Following is what my dataframe looks like. Expected_Output is my desired/target column.

I have table Y that contains two columns of values that are mutually exclusive (value1 and value2 can't both occur in the same group in table X)
How can I use pandas or SQL to create a column that has the Expected_Output column in table X  with the 'True' when a certain group contain two values in the X_Value column that in mutually exclusive?

Table Y

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| C | B |
| D | E |

Table X

| Group | X_Value | Expected_Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | True |
| 1 | B | True |
| 1 | C | True |
| 2 | D | True |
| 2 | E | True |
| 2 | F | True |
| 3 | G | False |
| 3 | H | False |
| 3 | I | False |

I tried

```
X['Expected_Output'] = (
    X.groupby('Group')
    .apply(lambda x: (x['X_Value'].isin(Y['Value1']).any())))
```

The expected output column was all non defined values unlike what I intended to happen.